# What's the right hardware and Photoshop configuration for big size canvas with a lot levels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution

with the new devices like iPad Pro I need to design UI with a lot of details and a lot of levels (also with smart object for a faster modifications) cause I need to have all on the same files, the result: a Photoshop LAGGY consequence (like 2 sec. to move an object and 20 sc to save a PNG 2048x1280)... What is your pipeline? I've 8 GB of Ram on my workstation, need more ram?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My approach has always been a systems approach rather than suboptimizing specific components. The critical elements in a computer system to run Photoshop are, in order of my preference:

1. RAM, with the prices today, add as much as your budget allows, certainly more than 8GB. If you are planning to keep your gear, this is where you can gain substantial improvements with modest investment
2. CPU, clearly faster the better. If possible, an i7 class CPU is better than an i5, or i3
3. Graphics card, the later versions of Photoshop and even Lightroom to some extent are able to use some GPU capabilities. Check the version of Photoshop you are using and find out what graphics capabilities it supports and move accordingly
4. Scratch disk, a fast separate scratch disk will add to the performance. Despite all the memory, Photoshop still offloads information from memory to disk. This process should not compete with program module switches and other system level disk access. Add a second hard disk drive and set Photoshop to use it for its scratch disk not your system drive C.

Allocate your budget to come up with a balanced "system". There is no sense in using the fastest CPU on a computer with 8GB RAM and a single drive. However, the most visible performance gain will likely come from adding more RAM to your system.

Comment: so you mean that isn't about photoshop pipeline but hardware performance, my settings was already right like you said. Thank you!

Comment: I don't really know how you set up Photoshop, but 8GB RAM is clearly on the rather low side. The file size you mentioned is not too large at all, you may also be suffering from the scratch disk performance. The more the number of levels you have the slower the save would be, that's the nature of the beast.

Comment: With large files, I've found the scratch disk size makes a considerable difference.  What setting are you using for it?